# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'username' in package 'android'

Tags: android

how do i solve this? error: No resource identifier found for attribute   'username' in package 'android'. my code is as follows:

```
<!--  Username Label -->         
  <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:textColor="#372c24"      
android:text="Username"/>      
<EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:layout_marginTop="5dip"       
android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"    
android:singleLine="true"
android:username="true"/>
```

Comment: remove this `android:username="true"` from `EditText`

Comment: The attribute `android:username` doesn't exist in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `android:username` from your code in `EditText`as no such field or attribute exist in android as of now.

This will remove the error.